# The Structured Streaming program cannot run continuously. After running for a few minutes, print [INFO] StateStore: 57

Tags: spark-streaming

After running for a few minutes, the program seems to stop running and keeps printing [INFO] StateStore: 57- Retrieved reference to StateStoreCoordinator: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.StateStoreCoordinatorRef@567563ae , no longer generating results

I don't understand where the problem is. I want the program to keep running and make some modifications

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.